# Create Action Bar in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm completely brand new to Android Developement and this is the first day I ever tried with Android Studio. I'm trying to create an action bar for my app following this link : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html

The link require me to Update activity so that it extends ActionBarActivity. However my Main Activity is currently extends to a ListActivity. Any idea how can I still add an action bar?

```
class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private NotesDataSource datasource;
    List<NoteItem> notesList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        datasource = new NotesDataSource(this);

        refreshDisplay();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Google has just generalized `ActionBar` into something called `Toolbar` that you can use without extending *ActionBarActivity*. You can learn more on their [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.tw/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help, just wondering is there any way I can still use the ActionBar as I'm following some tutorials from scratch using ActionBar.

Comment: I think for Toolbar it still ask me to extending ActionBarActivity http://android-developers.blogspot.tw/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html Please Help

Comment: I would recommend you to use ListFragment instead, which is compatible with ActionBarActivity